# How fill in input box on page Load in React?

Tags: reactjs

How can i fill all the input box values with the values as present inside of array `postComment`

I am having `postComment` as an array which contain values as well as blank values when a page is loading i want to store values in input boxes

here is mine code

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = {
  htmltag: `<div><p>Four independent <input type="text" /> testified to seeing him at the scene of the crime</p><p>Once upon a time there <input type="text" /> (live) a man called Damocles.</p><p>Rajeev failed in the examination because none of his answers were <input type="text" /> to the questions asked.</p><p>He traveled all <input type="text" /> the world when he was eighty years old.</p> </div>`
};

export default function App() {
  const postComment= ["a", "", "", "cd"];

  const dataToDiv = React.useRef(null);

  const handleanswer = () => {
    const inputs = dataToDiv.current.querySelectorAll("input");
    const formDataArray = inputs.map(input => input.value);
    console.log(formDataArray);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        onLoad={handleanswer}
        ref={dataToDiv}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.htmltag }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can use `useEffect` hook to do stuff once page is mounted in functional component. Suggested read is [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: Thanks @norbitrial the problem is fill in input box on page Load

Comment: @Khushboo you wanna set the default value for your inputs, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understood correctly, what you're trying to do, is to have the values that you have stored in `postComment` as default Values for your form.

Since you've decided to compose the html as string and set it via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, you could just access the `postComment` array when you create the HTML.

It would look something like this:

**Working Example:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-einstein-lggmg

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";


export default function App() {

  const postComment= ["a", "", "", "cd"];

  const data = {
    htmltag: `<div><p>Four independent <input type="text" value="${postComment[0]}"/> testified to seeing him at the scene of the crime</p><p>Once upon a time there <input type="text"  value="${postComment[1]}"/> (live) a man called Damocles.</p><p>Rajeev failed in the examination because none of his answers were <input type="text"  value="${postComment[2]}"/> to the questions asked.</p><p>He traveled all <input type="text"  value="${postComment[3]}"/> the world when he was eighty years old.</p> </div>`
  };

  const dataToDiv = React.useRef(null);

  const handleanswer = () => {
    const inputs = dataToDiv.current.querySelectorAll("input");
    const formDataArray = inputs.map(input => input.value);
    console.log(formDataArray);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        onLoad={handleanswer}
        ref={dataToDiv}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.htmltag }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

HOWEVER I don't really understand why you want to create the HTML manually, since this really limits you in what you can do with it.

You can check out the official React Documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) about how you would typically manage such a situation.

Comment: hey i cannot manipulate my ```htmltag``` so that is why i need to control in uncontrolled manner

Comment: But you want the data as `value` of the inputs, right?

Comment: Yes , but in uncontrolled manner because ```htmltag``` will be coming from API

Comment: Then you probably want to replace the inputs with inputs that have the value added like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-snowflake-9b9ry?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank but can you add a comment to it so that i can understand what going there..

Comment: Sure added it. If you have more questions let me know

Comment: Basically , I have not downgrade the vote and thanks once again